# operator === in JavaScript code change to three horizontal lines

Tags: javascript, linux, visual-studio-code

I am coding a game assignment in JavaScript and all the equal value comparison operators (===) change to three horizontal lines. I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and I have installed different types of JavaScript extensions but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: I dont know what your question is.

Comment: I see red squiggles on `computerScore` and `playerScore`, but none on the `===`. It looks like it might just be a weird font thing.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the fonts/styles of the editor? There are plugins that show triple equals as that glyph, but it doesn't change the underlying code.

Comment: Forget screenshots, use text copy-paste.

Answer (score 20):

Those are font ligatures. They are still `===`, it just changes the look to be a little cleaner and nicer. You'll see something similar if you type `>=` and `<=`, or `!=`. They'll probably become the mathematical symbols for their respective equalities. It looks like you're using the [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) font.

> From their [GitHub page](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode):
>
> [image: Ligatures]

Comment: Just to note: to change the font (tested in VS Code 1.41.0), it is under `File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Font` and the default font for VSCode is `Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings

Comment: In your text editor, disable `Font ligatures`... That's what replaces those symbols as you have described! You don't need to uninstall/change any font for this!

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, go to extensions and disable the Prettify extension.

Comment: Thanks so much. I uninstalled the FiraCode  and edited the font-family with 'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'.